# query for top 50 related tags for all tags with respective counts

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

How would you create a query to return all tags with their corresponding 25 most popular tags and counts and the tag itself with its own count?

For example, output would be like:

```
tag, related_tag, count, related_count
PHP, PHP, 90000, 90000 
PHP, wordpress, 9960, 1300
PHP, symfony, 15000, 1500
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/264011/top-50-related-tags?MyTag=):

```
-- Input a base tag.  The query then finds the top 50 related 
-- tags used with that base tag.

select TOP(50) count(t2.TagName) as "Count", t2.TagName as "Related Tag"

from PostTags as pt1
  INNER JOIN Tags as t1 ON pt1.TagId = t1.Id
  INNER JOIN PostTags as pt2 ON pt1.PostId = pt2.PostId AND pt1.TagId <> pt2.TagId
  INNER JOIN Tags as t2 ON pt2.TagId = t2.Id

where t1.TagName = ##MyTag:string##  -- MyTag: Base Tag
group by t2.TagName
order by count(t2.TagName) desc
```

This doesn't quite work the exact way your example output works.  This outputs just the related tags and how many questions the related tag is on that also have the base tag.  This matches your 'related_tag' and 'related_count' columns in your example.

This also requires you provide an input for the base tag, as just doing this query for every single tag is a bit much, there are so many tags, that such a query would take a while.

If this doesn't meet your needs, post a comment, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Works well, but I do need this for all tags. Doesn't matter if the query takes a very long time to run. I just need the csv output anyways. The first column needs to be the reference tag name, the second - the related tag name. So given the fact that there are 34000 or so tags in Stackoverflow, results returned would be possibly around the mark of 34000 + (34000 x 50), the 50 of course being variable, as all may not have 50 related tags.

Comment: @priyolahiri I doubt that the SEDE will allow you that (if a query takes too much time it would refuse to run it). I recommend downloading the database and running it locally.

Comment: If I was to download the database and run the query, what would be the query?

Answer (score -2):

Someone wrote [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/261773/score-stats-for-tag), and pasted the link into a chat room last week. It lists tags by tagname (alphabetical), and also gives you the "Count," "MinScore" (lowest-scored question on the tag) "MaxScore" (score of highest-voted question in tag), and "AvgScore."

Here's a screenshot of some of the results for SO:

[image]

(*the reason it got pasted into chat was (partly) because [a tag I invented has a very high average score](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19309355#19309355)*)